# Move files with map(shutil.move)

Tags: python

I'd like to move following books to specified `DirHTML` directory.

```
books = ['HTML-Head First HTML and CSS - 2nd Ed.pdf',
 'HTML and CSS - Design and Build Websites - Jon Duckett - November 2011.pdf',
 "Murach's HTML5 and CSS3 3rd Edition (2015).pdf",
 'HTML5-cheat-sheet.pdf']
```

Easily they can be moved to `DirHTML` with codes:

```
import shutil
for book in books:
    shutil.move(book, 'DirHTML')
```

When I tried

```
map(shutil.move, books, 'DirHTML')
```

There's no files moved.
How to enable the code working?

Comment: Read the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each argument to `map` after the first should be an `iterable`. Indeed, `'DirHTML'` *is* an iterable, but iterating it obtains `['D', 'i', 'r', 'H', 'T', 'M', 'L']` which is obviously not what you want.

If you insist on using `map` here, try

```
map(lambda x: shutil.move(x, 'DirHTML'), books)
```

or maybe

```
map(shutil.move, books, ['DirHTML'] * len(books))
```

neither of which is particularly transparent or elegant, and in the latter case, unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: Examining the error message you get in the traceback should reveal the problem to a reader, and would be important to include in your question even if you cannot make sense of it yourself. "Code does not work" is not a good question.

Answer (score 1):

First let me say this: you can use `map` this way, but I don't think it's a good idea. It's meant to transform iterables, not to have side effects. When used for the side effects, as you do, the original imperative code is IMO much clearer.

Now, if you insist to use map, read on. There are potentially two issues here.

First, as explained in other answers, you can't pass the destination directory the way you do. tripleee shows some solutions/workarounds; here's another one:

```
from functools import partial
map(partial(shutil.move, dst='DirHTML'), books)
```

Second, if you're using Python 3: map is lazy. It only evaluates its result when you iterate over it. For example, you could pass the result to `list()`:

```
list(map(partial(shutil.move, dst='DirHTML'), books))
```

Tip: write a little wrapper around `shutil.move` that prints its arguments, to better see exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

from the official python doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

> If additional iterable arguments are passed, function must take that
>   many arguments and is applied to the items from all iterables in
>   parallel

In your `map` snippet, it will act as:

```
for i, j in zip(books, 'DirHTML'):
    shutil.move(i, j)
```

the `DirHTML` argument is as work as you expected passed whole string into `move` but pass each character in sequence.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `zip` here? Just `for book in books: shutil.move(book, 'DirHtml')` would be a lot simpler, clearer, and more efficient.

Comment: just tried to translate his map snippet to make him understand why it not work as expected.